# What files get edited when the system time changes?

Tags: installation, boot, filesystem, time, date

If the system time is changed on Linux, what files get edited? I know the timezone is kept in etc/timezone but is there anything if the timezone is not changed, but the time is?

Answer (score 2):

The time is not kept in a file, because obviously it would not change.  It is kept by the system's real time clock, which counts time even when the system is off via a small battery.

Comment: I didnt ask if time gets stored in a file though? I asked what files get edited if the system time changes? If I change the system time what on my linux box is going to record the fact I changed the time?

Comment: @Sally, nothing... the real time clock just gets changed to a new time.